# Move Files from .txt

Tags: directory, mv, batch

I have all my files in a parent directory, "Folder".
I have a Text document with all their appropriate locations.
What I want to do is to move them from Parent directory back to their original locations using this text document.
I have this done in Windows, but the syntax is new to me and I'm struggling to move files back. This is what I have so far:

`for file in $(cat ~/Desktop/Folder/ListedFiles.txt); do mv "$file" ~/Desktop/NewFolder; done`

Comment: Thanks for this information and your speedy reply. I managed to get it working now! It works much better on Ubuntu than Windows, too. I was very surprised.

Comment: `for file in $(cat ~/Desktop/Folder/ListedFiles.txt); do ... ; done` will fail if any of the filenames contains whitespace and may fail if there are other shell-special characters - a safe construct is `while IFS= read -r file; do ... ; done < ~/Desktop/Folder/ListedFiles.txt`

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I did a combination of the two ad it seems to work flawlessly. Thanks you two for helping solve this issue for me.

`while IFS= read -r file; do cp --parents -f -r "$file" ~/Desktop/Folder/; done < ~/Desktop/ListedFiles.txt`

Answer (score 2):

From comments:

> Do not use `mv` and do use `cp -f`  while testing and `cp` when doing a final test (that one will error out on duplicates, `-f` does not) and after verifying you rm the source. `mv` is permanent and `cp` is repeatable. ALways have the destibation end in a `/` otherwise you might end up with 1 file named "NewFolder". With a / it errors out of "NewFolder" does not exist.

> To be sure it is doing the same action every time start with a cd to where your files are. The command as you show -can- be correct. Just lacks some safety ;) Windows txt files will have different line endings but that should normally not be a problem.

> `for file in $(cat ~/Desktop/Folder/ListedFiles.txt); do ... ; done` will fail if any of the filenames contains whitespace and may fail if there are other shell-special characters - a safe construct is `while IFS= read -r file; do ... ; done < ~/Desktop/Folder/ListedFiles.txt`

Solution used:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do cp --parents -f -r "$file" ~/Desktop/Folder/; done < ~/Desktop/ListedFiles.txt
```

Comment: Made some edits. No need for referencing my name on the quotes. I made comments on purpose and could have made it an answer if I wanted the credits. Probably the same for steeldriver ;)